# AEM6.1, the component that bake in the html directly won't work correctly in touch UI

Tags: components, aem

I use sly **data-sly-resource="${@ path='column-1-title', resourceType='wcm/foundation/components/text'}"**   to bake in the text-sightly component directly(**cq:include** tag also have the same problem). But after I authored the content of the text, a 404 error arises in the console. And the page can't be authored anymore until I reload the page.
[CLICK HERE TO LOOK 404 NOT FOUND ERROR IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UCGmz.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
resourceType='foundation/components/text'
```

We have also observed that using "'wcm/foundation/components/text'" has issues in TouchUI.

Answer (score 0):

We need to specify a proper sling:resourceSuperType for the component that be baked in.